# git commit and git tag in azure devops yml based pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a nice way to commit the changes file and create a tag in azure DevOps yaml based pipeline?

My scenario will be for a node js based build:
Each build, it will change the package.json version by using `npm version patch`
In the end, It will push the package.json to the build branch (Obviously with condition branch==master) and will tag and push a branch as well.

The dirty way can be:

```
- bash : |
     git add filename.ext
     git push origin HEAD:branchName
     git tag -a tagName -m 'tag message' 
     git push --tags
  displayName: 'Git Commit and Tag from pipeline'
```

Comment: Your solution could be the best what you can get. I just only warn you to have properly configured builds (I mean triggers) or add phrase `[Skip CI]` to avoid circular dependency.

Comment: Agree. My CI trigger has a condition to skip If a commit is from CI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in as yaml build steps, but the important part is that you need the pipeline to have permission to do the push and the simplest way is to keep the credentials from the checkout as below.

You then need to grant the [Project Collection Build Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) **Create tag** and **Contribute** (add/remove files) permissions.

I also found I had to set the working directory for the push to work

```
steps:
# Check out the code and keep the token so we can tag the repository
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

--- rest of pipeline

# Tag the current branch with the version number
- script: |
    git add filename.ext
    git push origin
    git tag -a tagName -m 'tag message' 
    git push --tags
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  displayName: 'Git Commit and Tag from pipeline'
```

Answer (score 12):

You are right, to commit the changes and push to source repo in azure devops pipeline, you probably have to run the git commands in script tasks.

In the script task, your accountName in the repo clone url needs to replaced with `$(System.AccessToken)` for authentication purpose (eg. `https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/yourOrg/yourProj/_git/repoName`).

You can check below example to tag and push a azure branch.

```
- bash: | 
        git config --global user.email "your@email.com"
        git config --global user.name "yourUsername"

        #git add filename.ext
        git add .
        git commit -m "message" 

        git push https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/yourOrg/yourProj/_git/repoName HEAD:master -q

        git tag -a tagName -m 'tag message'
        git push https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/yourOrg/yourProj/_git/repoName tagName
```

Comment: Awesome! I don't have much reputation to give you +1, hence specifying in the comment

Answer (score 2):

Azure DevOps publish good documentation now `Enable scripts to run Git commands´. Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

1. You have to configure

```sh
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

2. Go to the Project settings --> select repository --> choose repository from the list(The one you want to commit from a pipeline)--> click on Permission(on top)-->In the search box , search for `Project Collection Build Service`, once it appears in the dropdown, select it and set the permission you want (attached image for your reference)
   [image: List item]

Then you are done. you can do all the git activity you want based on the permission you set on the above step.
Note- Take extra care of your Build Trigger configuration, Otherwise when you commit anything from your pipeline on the repository, your pipeline will trigger again and again ..and will become circular.  To avoid that, on your commit message add [skip ci] to avoid circular build.

Answer (score 2):

For tagging, you can use 'Label Sources' feature which is also available for yaml based pipelines.
Refer to this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#label-sources

Comment: Best answer to use automatic tagging