# Add tags to repository in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, tags

I am new to Azure DevOps. I need to add tags to repository and while the build is executing it should read the tag name from a txt file and create accordingly.

Comment: Just to clarify things - by tags, do you mean `git tags` or some other specific/custom tags that you are using in your workflow? The part that mentioned `.txt` file confused me.

Comment: Adding Tags in Azure DevOps when the build is success. By default it will take the tag name as $(build.buildNumber), here I want to add the tag name as a custom one which is mentioned in the txt file. For example, I have mentioned tag name as 1.2.3 in my txt file. So during the build successful completion it should create the tag for that successful build as 1.2.3. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I tried using Powershell and the build is getting success, but the build tags are not getting created.There is no issue as well, and not sure on the reason why tag is not getting created.

Comment: Hi @Dinaa According to your title of question, you need add tags to repository not build. The API I shared will tag your git repo not the build itself. For tag a build, you should use the Rest API which LJ. suggested. Hope it's clearly.

Answer (score 0):

`During the build successful completion, it should create the tag for that successful build.`

I think the easiest way to automate tag creation would be by using [Tags REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/tags/add%20build%20tags?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

The idea behind this would be to add an additional script at the end of a successful build, that calls the API and creates the necessary tag.

The script might look similar to this:

```
- script: |
    export TAG_NAME="$(cat tag-file.txt)" ##Somehow export the tag name as env variable
    export ORGANIZATION="organization_name" ##If you use variable groups, you can add it there and skip this line.
    curl -d "" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic $(PERONSAL_ACCESS_TOKEN)" \
     -X PUT https://dev.azure.com/$(ORGANIZATION)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/tags/$(TAG_NAME)?api-version=6.0
  condition: succeeded()
```

You can create personal access token by following [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat) instruction. Before you use this token to invoke REST API, you have to convert it to `Base64` string. For that you can use [THIS](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B7oa7d) script.

Comment: Under Which task can I add the yaml script above. Since I could not find a task for yaml in task group.

Comment: Task equal to `- script` in this case, would be `Command Line Script`. But I think either one of these should work: `Command Line Script`, `Bash` or `PowerShell`. Also, check the PatrickLu's answer, it might be more suitable for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

LJ. shared the solution which uses YAML pipeline. You could directly add that part in your `xx.yml`  file.

According to your description, seems you are using Classic UI editor.

Then you could either use [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) or [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to call your script.

Besides, that Rest API is adding tag to a build.

Cause you just want to tag a repo, you could directly use git command instead.

You then need to grant the [Project Collection Build Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) **Create tag** and **Contribute** (add/remove files) permissions.

For detail samples ,please refer [git commit and git tag in azure devops yml based pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035576/git-commit-and-git-tag-in-azure-devops-yml-based-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample YAML pipeline task that creates an Annotated Git Tag.
The main benefit that I see compared to invoking `git tag` command is that your pipeline does not need `Contribute` permission. Having `Create Tag` permission is enought.

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Create Git Tag using inline script
  env: 
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken) # enables you to use the $(System.AccessToken) to authenticate the REST call
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $rootUrl = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis"
      $authorizationHeader =  @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }

      $message = "YOUR GIT TAG MESSAGE" # TODO: set your message
      $body = "{ `"name`": `"$Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`", `"taggedObject`": { `"objectId`": `"$Env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION`" }, `"message`": `"$message`" }"
      $createTagUrl = "$rootUrl/git/repositories/$($env:Build_Repository_Name)/annotatedtags?api-version=6.0" # api-version=6.0 may change in the future!
      $createTagResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $createTagUrl -Method POST -Headers $authorizationHeader -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
      if ($createTagResponse -ne $Null) 
      {
          Write-Host $createTagResponse
          Write-Host "Git Tag Created!"
      }
    failOnStderr: true
```