# Azure DevOps - How can I have my powershell script output data to a text file that is located on the same Repo (git) as my script on Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-repos

I've got a powershell script located on Azure repo (git), I need that script to output data to a text file located on the same repo when I run the build. However when I use the path ./textFile.txt the text file is created on the vm box rather than on the repo.

How can I have the script output the data to the text file on the repo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git commit and git tag in azure devops yml based pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035576/git-commit-and-git-tag-in-azure-devops-yml-based-pipeline)

Comment: This is helpful in pointing me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When a build is triggered in Azure DevOps, the git repo (specified branch) is cloned to an agent (vm box as you imagine). That implies the execution of the script and output are limited to the agent.

Now, to meet the need, you need to perform git actions like you do on your local machine to create a new branch and continue with a PullRequest into target remote branch. After the merge (you can automate this as well with Azure DevOps restapi), the output is within the branch that was used in the build process.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: I tried using the AzDo rest api, but that won't append to the txt file on the repo it deletes it's content and puts the new content in. Is there a way to append to an existing text file?

Comment: AzDo api provides updating a file. Check it out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-file